# Collapsing a list with list icons from font-awesome

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm trying to collapse a portion of an unordered list using Bootstrap/jQuery and fontawesome. Right now I'm nesting lists, which I think is semantically valid.

It appears that when I add the .collapse class to a `<ul>`, the icons I have set as bullets disappear. Am I doing something wrong, or might this be some odd conflict between fontawesome/Bootstrap?

This is the code, and here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NDg4W/) illustrating the problem:

```
<ul class="icons-ul">
    <li><i class="icon-li icon-cog"></i><a href="#">List item</a></li>
    <li><i class="icon-li icon-chevron-down"></i><a href="#list-more" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#list-more">More</a>
        <ul id="list-more" class="icons-ul collapse">
            <li><i class="icon-li icon-cog"></i><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><i class="icon-li icon-cog"></i><a href=#"">Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I was ready to file a bug report with font-awesome, but since the documentation doesn't make any reference of nested lists using the .icons-ul class, I'm unsure if I'm going about things the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's `.collpase` and FontAwesome's `.icons-ul` do not seem to play nicely together.
Further inspection is necessary, but the issue would seem to be how bootstrap's `.collapse` uses `overflow: hidden`, and fontawesome's `.icon-li` uses `position: absolute; left: -2.142857142857143em;`, which means the visibility of the icons will get cut off.

Anyways, here's a modification of your code that I believe accomplishes the task at hand.

http://jsbin.com/ifequd/1/edit

Note that in the html, I've changed the source so that the icon is within the `<a>` tag; I was going nuts from a usability perspective because I could not click on the icon to trigger the menu.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="icons-ul">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-li icon-cog"></i>List item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#list-more" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#list-more"><i class="icon-li icon-chevron-down"></i>More</a>
        <ul id="list-more" class="icons-ul collapse">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-li icon-cog"></i>Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-li icon-cog"></i>Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.collapse {
  left: -2.142857142857143em;
}
.collapse li {
  left: 2.142857142857143em;
}

a i {
  color: #333;  
}

a:hover i {
  text-decoration: none;  
}
```

Alternatively, you could just **not use** the `.icon-li` class.
http://jsbin.com/ofeziq/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think you're right from a usability perspective regarding the icon being clickable--I had not done so due to semantics (should a bullet point be clickable?) but I think it makes more sense to do so. Any reason why the CSS contains such weird numbers?

Comment: @Corey - https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/css/font-awesome.css#L74-87